# How do I create a grep process with fork that will accept data from a pipe in Linux C programming

Tags: c, linux, pipe

If I create a process with fork(), such as grep, how do I pass it data to process? When I use write I get the error  $ grep: (standard input): Bad file descriptor;

Command I'm running **ps aux | grep notepad**

```
        child = fork();         

    //C1 execute first line of command line
    if(child == 0)
    {
        close(1); //close stdout
        dup(pfds[1]); // make stdout pfds[1]
        close(pfds[0]);

        //execute the args
        execvp(args[0], args);
            perror("FAILED TO EXECUTE!!!");
                exit(-1);

    }
    //Parent assume execution control
    else
    {
        int in = dup(0); //duplicate in
        int out = dup(1); //duplicate out

        //Close the parents in and redirect to pipe
        close(0);
        dup(pfds[0]);
        close(pfds[1]);

        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0); // wait for child to die
            read(pfds[0], pbuff, P_BUFSIZE); //read from pipe

        //Close the parents out and redirect to pipe
        close(1);
        dup(pfds[1]);
        close(pfds[0]);

            write(pfds[0], pbuff, sizeof(pbuff)-1);

        pid = fork();

        //C2 process use the data of the old C1 process
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            //Close childs in and redirect to pipe;
            close(0);
            dup(pfds[0]);

            execvp(args2[0], args2);
                perror("Execution failure);
                    exit(-1)        

        }
```

Comment: You need to use `dup2`.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a shot but could you explain why this is happening? If I redirect the standard input to a pipe why does it not pick up the data in the pipe?