# Program control does not return after multiple forks leaving zombie and process hanging

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe

Trying to simulate the functionality of the | command line argument in Linux. I've already parsed the arguments properly but program control is not returning to my main process and I've got one uninterruptible process and a zombie - which I don't understand how since I figured if I spawned the processes they should terminate on their own as they are just regular linux processes. I added the processes below. I'm just running  ps aux | grep notepad. I posted previously here [How do I create a grep process with fork that will accept data from a pipe in Linux C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003256/how-do-i-create-a-grep-process-with-fork-that-will-accept-data-from-a-pipe-in-li) but this issue is different as I have the correct output I just don't want the processes to hang.

```
1000      4074  0.0  0.0   4392   824 pts/0    S+   21:38   0:00 grep notepad
1000      4075  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z+   21:38   0:00 [ps] <defunct>
1000      4076  0.0  0.0   4944  1172 pts/0    R+   21:38   0:00 ps aux


int ppid = fork ();

    if(ppid == 0)
    {
               pid = fork();

        //Parent assume execution control
        if(ppid == 0 && pid != 0)
        {       
            //Close the parents in and redirect to pipe
            close(0);
            dup(pfds[0]);
            close(pfds[1]);
            execvp(secondargs[0], secondargs);
                perror("exect failed to");
                    exit(-1);
        }   
        //C1 execute first line of command line
        else if(pid == 0)
        {
            close(1); //close stdout
            dup(pfds[1]); // make stdout pfds[1]
            close(pfds[0]);

            //execute the args
            execvp(args[0], args);
                perror("exec failed to");
                    exit(-1);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Processes must be wait()ed for. The zombie entry exists to retain the process return code until the wait() picks it up, since the RC might carry important information about how the child process exited.

If you don't want to deal with keeping appropriate wait()s spinning until the children exit, one standard trick is to "double fork" -- spawn an intermediate process which launches the desired child process and then kills itself. That results in the child being disowned, at which point it becomes child of the system process and the system-default wait() handling takes over to absorb the zombie and discard the return code.

Websearch for "unix fork zombie wait", or some combination of those terms, will find examples and more extensive discussion of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that the problem is that you create the pipe before you fork any children (since there is no `pipe()` call in the code fragment).

Unfortunately, you don't close the pipe in the original parent process, so it can still write to the write end of the pipe.  Therefore, even though the `ps` has exited, the system knows that the parent could still write on the pipe (even though it won't) so `grep` never gets told EOF.

In other words, `grep` is waiting for the original parent process to close the pipe, and the original parent process is waiting for `grep` to finish (or, at least, it might be).  If the original parent exits, then `grep` will get EOF and will exit, and the system will clean up both corpses.  If the original parent is waiting, then it is going to wait for a very long time.